# How do I specify ":layout => false" in Rails' respond_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this setup:

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html, :js, :xml, :json

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)
  end
end
```

Now I am trying to make it so, if `params[:format] =~ /(js|json)/`, `render :layout => false, :text => @users.to_json`.  How do I do that with `respond_with` or `respond_to` and inherited_resources?

Comment: Just guesses, but maybe `render false` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Something like:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with @users do |format|
    format.json { render :layout => false, :text => @users.to_json }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you need JSON for an Ajax request

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html, :js, :xml, :json

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users, :layout => !request.xhr? )
  end
end
```

This seems like the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 18):

Or to prevent you having to hardcode responses for each format in each action.

If you have no layouts for any of the actions in this controller it would be nicer to do:

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html, :js, :xml, :json
  layout false

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)
  end
end
```

Comment: In rails 3 use layout: false - nil will load the default layout. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11355276/398696

Answer (score 8):

I love @anthony's solution, but didn't work for me... I had to do:

```
respond_with(@users) do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => !request.xhr? }
end
```

*ps: posting an "answer" instead of a comment because stackoverflow comment formatting and "return key == submit" is infuriating!*

Answer (score 5):

I just found this out:

Even if it's JSON, Rails is still looking for a layout. As such, the only layout that it finds, in our case, is `application.html`.

Solution: Make a JSON layout.

So for instance, if you put an empty `application.json.erb` with a single `= yield` inside, next to your HTML one, the HTML layout is bettered by the JSON one. You can even use this to surround your JSON with metadata or things like that.

```
<%# app/views/layouts/application.json.erb %>

<%= yield %>
```

No other parameters needed, it automagically works!

*Tested in Rails 4 only*

Comment: Tested in Rails 3, works just fine. While it isn't an answer for the question asked, it is still the answer for the question a lot of us mean for real.

Comment: Works for me in Rails 4. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: I've just checked in Rails 4.2. If you name your layout file `application.html.slim`, it wouldn't be treated as layout file for json; whoever, if you name your layout file as `application.slim`.. then it *would* be treated as layout file for JSON. (replace slim with erb should do the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
  layout -> (controller) { controller.request.xhr? ? false : 'application' }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this on your show action.

```
def show
  render :layout => !request.xhr?
end
```

:)