# Rails 3 respond_with: show "show" layout on resource creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I've got a `comment` resource. I've got a controller that handles `respond_with`, and for right now, it's supposed to be serving up all JSON responses (which is happening correctly). I'm using [Rabl](http://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to handle my JSON/XML rendering, and I'm DRY-ing things up a little. I have the *proper* way I want a `comment` to be rendered at `comments/show.rabl`.

```
object @comment

attributes :id, :body, :a_few_more_things
```

When a POST call is made on `/comments/` (which fires the `create` method on my controller), I want Rails to return the `comment` in the same format as the `show` view (above). I've got, in my `create` function...

```
def create
  # Skip some code, save it, ya-da ya-da
  respond_with(@comment, :layout => 'comments/show')
end
```

This isn't working; it's just returning a flat JSON implementation of the `comment` with all of the attributes on it. It's not using my `show.rabl` at `comments/show.rabl`. *How do I get my `create` action to return the @comment using `show.rabl` as the layout?*

I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978800/in-rails-3-how-do-i-render-with-layout-in-respond-with-using-a-custom-format) specifies the full path and extension of the layout file; I shouldn't have to do that, should I? Am I using the wrong `:symbol_option`? Should it be `:location`?

Comment: take a peak at [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by creating a Rabl template at `comments/create.rabl`.

```
object @comment

extends "comments/show"
```

And that's all she wrote. Rails looks for the `create.rabl` view, which accepts one objects and just renders the fields defined in `comments/show.rabl`.

Thanks to [Martin Harrigan](https://twitter.com/harrigan/status/153916037795024897) for reminding me I still had my question open!

Answer (score 0):

You can use, to stay dry :

```
render :show, :status => :created
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails4 you can specify template:

```
def create
  respond_with @comment, status: :created, template: 'comments/show'
end
```