# rails 4 -- working with js format from ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm still working on learning Rails, and I have a page with team information that will get updated based on a team's icon click, which fires an ajax call to the controller to populate some tabs.

I've read some [good info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367426/rendering-a-partial-from-a-controller-in-rails) about how to use `format.js` in the controller to render a partial from a `js.coffee` or `js.erb` file.

The problem I'm running into is in the `coffeescript` I think. Right now, I'm getting some data called `@schedules` from the controller, and passing it to a `schedule.js.coffee` file that *should* populate a partial for each record returned and attach it to a table.

```
// schedule.js.coffee
$.each @schedules, (schedule) ->
    ($ '#schedule_data').append("<%= j render(partial: 'schedules/schedule', locals: { s: schedule }) %>")
```

This throws an error

```
`> undefined local variable or method `schedule' for #<#<Class:0x007fe535cd2900>:0x007fe535d32a30>`
```

I tried simplifying the coffeescript to just log the output:

```
$.each @schedules, (schedule) ->
    console.log(schedule)
```

but this prints nothing.

Am I missing something? I am very inexperienced with coffeescript, but it seems like I should be getting some data-- I verified that the schedule items do exist for this team item.

Comment: Please post your related controller code and the partial file.

Comment: I don't think you are meant to use rails variables in coffeescript, so $.each @schedules, appears wrong to me...

Comment: try a simple console.log or an alert statement without any loop inside your coffee file

Comment: I think @RubyRacer is right, you're mixing your coffeescript with your ruby where you're calling `$.each`...  What if you do `$.each <%= j @schedules %>, (schedule) -> ` etc?  I doubt it would do what you want, but you should get something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ERB**

Further to `RubyRacer`'s comment, the most important thing to note here is the use of Rails code inside your JS. Although processing `.js.coffee` and `.js.erb` files in the backend of your system *does* allow for Rails code to be used, it has to follow the same syntax as it would in an `html.erb` (same preprocessor):

```
 // schedule.js.coffee
<% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
    $('#schedule_data').append("<%= j render(partial: 'schedules/schedule', locals: { s: schedule }) %>")
<% end %>
```

---

**Error**

A more curious problem is your error:

```
undefined local variable or method `offer' for #<Class:0x007fe535cd2900>:0x007fe535d32a30>
```

This suggests you have a problem inside your model (where you're referencing the `offer` method of your `schedule` object). I think the problem would be caused by your incomplete JS previously (as you weren't passing the right data)

If the problem persists after attempting my fix above, please comment & I'll help!

Comment: @RichPeck-- sorry, you're correct in noting the error message. I posted late at night after staring at the problem far too long and used the wrong variable name when I printed the error. It is fixed above.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Rich-- that was indeed the problem. I was mixing js and ruby. However, the script is not throwing an error but is not doing anything either. Does coffeescript require a `document.ready` statement or something of that kind to trigger it? Or should this be called automatically by the controller?

Comment: Here is the returned / compiled coffeescript, which seems correct but does nothing: `(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    alert('yo');
    return $('#schedule_body').append("<tr>\n <td>July 1<\/td>\n <td>Oklahoma State Cowboys<\/td>\n <td>OK City<\/td>\n <\/tr>");
  });

}).call(this);`