# Ruby on Rails - Show the same modal with different content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a home page with a list of software in a table.

With this link I open my softwares pages in modals:

```
<% = link_to software_path (software), remote: true do %> ... <% end%>
```

I created a script allowing me to open my modals when I click on td with class `.clickable` and not open modals when I click on a td with class `.no-click`.

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
      $('#software-modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

structure :

_software.html.erb open _software_modal.html.erb

Problem:
When I try to open my modals via the script, it's always the same modal that opens. That is, the modal of software 1 opens when I click on software 2, software 3, ... but no problem when I just use the link.

So I have a problem with id or something like that in my script ...

Can you help me ?

> **EDIT 1:**  With the response of VAD I tried to search the id with data-id.

_software.html.erb

```
<tr class="clickable" data-id="<%= software.id %>">
...
</tr>
<div id='software-content'></div>
```

_software_modal.html.erb

```
<div id="software-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
...
</div>
```

show.js.erb

```
$('#software-content').html("<%= j render 'software_modal', software: @software %>");
$('#software-modal').modal('show');
```

this show.js.erb allows me to open my modals via example links:

```
<%= link_to software.name, software_path(software), remote: true,class:"no-click" %>
```

but not via a clickable table.

So I added a script in _software.html.erb that makes my table clickable:

```
  $(".clickable[data-id]").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
      window.location = '/softwares/' + $(this).attr('data-id');
    }
});
```

I also tried with data-link, ... is there a way to open this window.location in a modal (like the link)? I searched for several hours yesterday but I did not find anything ..

> **EDIT 2**

following the response of @VAD with render layout: false, we can put:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout proc{|c| c.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end
```

which allows to have a false render for the js and true render for html. And so to keep my html pages with my starting layout.

Thx @dogenpunk 
[Render without layout when format is JS (needs drying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729476/render-without-layout-when-format-is-js-needs-drying)

Comment: updated my answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have different modals for every place you want to show the modal from. Like for `software1` you need to show the modal with content relative to this particular object. For `software2` you'll need to show the same model but with a brand new content relative to `software2`

Another option (and the better one) is that you may have one single modal for every `Software` object but by some event (for example actually showing the modal) you'll update the modal content with the data specific for this particular `Software` object. You may use some controller action for that

**Additional**

Try to pass software id as data parameters in your `clickable` elements and then to update your modal content with ajax and like that

```
<div class = 'clickable' data-id = "#{software.id}">
</div>

$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
      $.get('/softwares/' + $(this).attr('data_id'), function(data) {
        $('#software-modal body').html(data);
      }); 
      $('#software-modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Of course I can't give precise code so you'll need to adjust it according to you current setup

**Update**

The idea is that you have `show` action in `softwares_controller.rb` which eventually renders the content for your modals:

```
def show
  // some code you need
  render layout: false
end
```

It will render `show.html.erb` view. In that view you should keep the html for your modal content. Notice that the action will render that view without layout. You need this because you will soon take this html and will put it into the modal, so you don't need any extra html like the layout.

So, you have an action which render the modal content for every `software` object by its id.

Now you need to put it into the modal.

You have `clickable` elements in your markup. You attach correspondent `software` ids to them as `data-id`. Then in your jquery code you use these ids to construct a url like this:

```
'/softwares/' + $(this).attr('data_id')
```

This url will lead to your `show` action in `softwares_controller.rb`. So by clicking on one of `clickable` elements you take the id, generate the url with it, send request to the url, get the response (the modal content) and then put it into the modal like this:

```
$.get('/softwares/' + $(this).attr('data_id'), function(data) {
  $('#software-modal body').html(data);
});
```

Then you show the modal with already updated content:

```
$('#software-modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Sorry for the delay but i still look for several hours yesterday before answering :)
There is something that I have trouble understanding in your answer, I found my urls of my softwares but I can not open them in modals. I edit my question .. maybe could you help me :)
Thanks again

Comment: Ok thank you I begin to understand the principle!
I managed to open my pages in modals, however this technique poses some inconvenience it seems to me.

What about SEO if my pages /softwares/1 no returns layout ?

Thank you, your answers allow me to improve my knowledge!

Comment: @ClydeT, unfortunately I'm not proficient in SEO so can't suggest you anything. We just used this solution within the project working with the tables of entities and the modals for each of them, so I thought this matched your case exactly. About the layout. The layout will be there, it will be around the view  where your `clickable` elements are. If you need to show the `software` objects somewhere other than in the modal, you'll need to use different actions or pass some bool value to the action to check if you need to render the layout along with the view or not

Comment: Hello @VAD, I have one last little question ... is there any way to make sure to open a render via the script rather than in the softwares_controller?

For example, I tried several solutions such as
$ ('# software-modal body'). html ("<% = j render 'software_modal_test', software: @software%>");

instead of :
$ ('# software-modal body'). html (data);

But without success ...

Comment: I have finally found a solution that allows for a false rendering with my modal js but no false with my html page! I edit my question if it interests you :)