# Why is `layout nil` not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I just upgraded my Rails site from Rails 2 to Rails 3.2.

On my old controller I had:

```
class Foo::BarController < ApplicationController
   layout nil 
   ... 
end
```

However now that I upgraded to Rails 3 it seems I need to change that to:

```
layout false
```

The documentation on [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) claims that `layout nil` should work fine:

> Layout declarations cascade downward in the hierarchy ...
>
> class OldPostsController < SpecialPostsController
>      layout nil

I have the following relevant gems in my Gemfile.lock

GEM

```
actionpack (3.2.6)
  activemodel (= 3.2.6)
  activesupport (= 3.2.6)
  builder (~> 3.0.0)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
builder (3.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
haml (3.1.6)

jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
```

Is this a documented change somewhere, or is it a related gem monkey patching something?

Comment: 'cause an == was changed to an === ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) explains it like this:

If the specified layout is:

- a string: the string is the template name
- a symbol: call the method specified by the symbol, which will return the template name
- `false`:    there is no layout
- `true`:     raise an `ArgumentError`
- `nil`:      force default layout behavior with inheritance

So the meaning of `nil` changed from no layout to "force default layout behavior with inheritance". Seems the explanation in Rails Guides is incorrect.

Comment: jeez... this rails 3 upgrade is the gift that does not stop taking

Comment: I suspect it is this change https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5ad52152117ecda1166359c499bcd03ae6be3365 will tweet josevalim

Comment: Yes, looks like that's the one. Good luck with your upgrade ;-)

Comment: I bet someone thought they were real clever by having a nil value do something different than a false value.

Comment: @LarryK Jose says he did this as a performance optimisation, the semantics being different to `render` semantics is really confusing though imho